# Meaning of $e^{i\theta}$ inside a matrix

Tags: matrices, rotations

I know about the matrix exponential, but I am struggling to interpret the effects of the following matrix:

\begin{bmatrix}a & 0 \\ 0 & be^{i\theta}\end{bmatrix}

We scale all components $e_1$ by $a$, but what happens to the basis vectors $e_2$, are they scaled and rotated? Or is it a 3D rotation matrix?

Comment: Accepting complex inputs, the second input will be rotated by $\theta$ and scaled by $b$ (if $b$ is real). I’m not sure if this can be geometrically realised as a rotation in $3D$ because two complex inputs $\to$ $4$ degrees of freedom

Comment: It could be a matrix from $\mathbb{C}^2$ to $\mathbb{C}^2$. Alternatively, it is a (strange) way of representing a block-diagonal matrix from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to  $\mathbb{R}^3$, where there is a $2 \times 2$ block $b\cos \theta$, $-b\sin \theta$, (next line) $b\sin \theta$, $b\cos \theta$.

Comment: @FShrike the context of this matrix is in a 2 qubit quantum system, so it makes sense that there are 4 degrees of freedom. But mathematically I am unsure how to interpret this.